# How do I make independent lists within in a list?

Tags: python, list

```
seats = 4  # user can choose an even input, I put 4 for this example
rows = 4  # user can choose an even or odd input, I put 4 for this example
seats_in_row_list = [i for i in string.ascii_uppercase[:seats]]
main_seat_list = [seats_in_row_list for i in range(rows)]
```

The output is:

```
[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']]
```

But when I try to change 'A' to 'X' in the first list all of the lists change:

```
[['X', 'B', 'C', 'D'], ['X', 'B', 'C', 'D'], ['X', 'B', 'C', 'D'], ['X', 'B', 'C', 'D']]
```

What I'm looking for is this output:

```
[['X', 'B', 'C', 'D'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly)

Comment: use `main_seat_list = [seats_in_row_list.copy() for i in range(rows)]`

Comment: @GoodDeeds It's similar, but not a duplicate. The lists in that question have repeated values created from list multiplication, and none of the answers mention `list.copy()`, which is the right solution here.

Comment: @wjandrea You are right, I retracted my vote. But I think the link serves as a useful reference to understand the cause of the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use copy method to have a copy of the individual list before assigning

```
main_seat_list = [seats_in_row_list.copy() for i in range(rows)]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you aren't using `seats_in_row_list` for anything other than the construction of `main_seat_list`, you should just inline the definition. Calling `list` here would be simpler than using a list comprehension.

```
seats = 4
rows = 4
main_seat_list = [list(string.ascii_uppercase[:seats]) for i in range(rows)]
```